# Deducing type of template parameter expression

Tags: c++, templates, arithmetic-expressions, type-deduction

How can the type of an template argument expression be deduced? For example, regarding the following code:

```
template< typename T >
class A
{
//....
};

template< typename T_1, typename T_2 >
class B
{
  auto foo()
  {
    return A</* Type of "T_1+T_2"*/>();
  }
};
```

How can the type of `T_1+T_2` be deduced? For example, it could be `T_1=float` and `T_2=int`and consequently, `foo` should return `A<float>()` (since summing up an an `integer` with a `float` results in a `float`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `decltype` and `std::declval`. I would also suggest to typedef the result type for better readability:

```
template< typename T_1, typename T_2 >
class B
{
  typedef decltype(std::declval<T_1>() + std::declval<T_2>()) result_type;
  auto foo() -> result_type
  {
    return A<result_type>();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) with [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval):

```
return A<decltype(std::declval<T_1>() + std::declval<T_2>())>();
```

`decltype` gives you the type of an expression. `std::declval` creates a reference to a type out of nowhere for use in `decltype` expressions.